# Неправильное отображение русских символов Java на сервере

Tags: java, ubuntu, сервер, charset

Есть сервер с виртуалкой Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab133.2 x86_64)

Установил:

JAVA
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.16.04.1-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b03, mixed mode)

Mysql, php и апач

прога на джаве парсит странички в интернете и записывает данные в бд, которые потом можно достать по пхпшному апи, но столкнулся с проблемой кодировки русских символов в java, вывожу программой строчку "привет" получаю через I/O в терминале "??????". C английскими символами все ок. Было подозрение на БД но там везде UTF-8. Проблемка явно с java, при запуске пытался приписывать java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar work.jar но не помогло. Помогите, если встречались с такой проблемой, пожалуйста =)

Comment: Вывод строчки и запись в базу - это две разные проблемы. В какой кодировке исходный текст java-программы? При компиляции эта кодировка компилятору была указана? Парсер правильно определяет кодировку страничек? При подключении к БД кодировка была указана?

Comment: Проблема была в сервере, если запускать с -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar (путь файла), то все ок а в консоли кракозябры, которые на деле нормальные символы utf8